# Why doing bootstrap with `sklearn` and doing bootstrap with `statsmodels` yields different coefficients?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, statsmodels

I have a dataset: link to download [here](https://r-data.pmagunia.com/dataset/r-dataset-package-islr-default).

I'm performing LogisticRegression using both `sklearn` and `statsmodels`.

When doing bootstrap to estimate `coef` and `std_err`, the `coef` yielded from the `bootstrap_sklearn` is different from the `coef` that I get doing `non_bootstrap_sklearn`, `non_bootstrap_statsmodels` and `bootstrap_statsmodels`.

First, the 'real' coefficients using `statsmodels`:

```
endog = (Default["default"] == "Yes").astype(int)
exog = sm.add_constant(Default[["income", "balance"]])
mod = sm.Logit(endog, exog)
res = mod.fit()
res.summary()
```

Output:

```
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const        -11.5405      0.435    -26.544      0.000     -12.393     -10.688
income      2.081e-05   4.99e-06      4.174      0.000     1.1e-05    3.06e-05
balance        0.0056    0.00022     24.835      0.000       0.005       0.006
==============================================================================
```

We have `income_coef = 2e-05`, `income_std_err = 5e-06`, `balance_coef = 0.0056` and `balance_std_err = 0.00022`.

I then perform bootstrap using `sklearn.LogisticRegression`:

```
np.random.seed(17)
num_estimates = 1000
boot_estimates = np.empty((num_estimates, 2))

for i in range(num_estimates):
    clf = LogisticRegression(penalty = "none", solver = "lbfgs")
    sample = resample(Default)
    coefs = boot_fn(sample, clf)
    boot_estimates[i, 0] = coefs[0, 0]
    boot_estimates[i, 1] = coefs[0, 1]
    print(f"{i+1} out of {num_estimates}", end="\r")
```

And bootstrap with `statsmodels.Logit`:

```
np.random.seed(17)
num_estimates = 1000
boot_estimates = np.empty((num_estimates, 2))
for i in range(num_estimates):
    sample = resample(Default)
    endog = (sample["default"] == "Yes").astype(int)
    exog = sm.add_constant(sample[["income", "balance"]])
    mod = sm.Logit(endog, exog)
    res = mod.fit(disp = False)
    boot_estimates[i, 0] = res.params["income"]
    boot_estimates[i, 1] = res.params["balance"]
    print(f'{i+1} of {num_estimates}', end='\r')
```

I then add everything to a `df` for easy comparison (using `.mean()` and `.sem()` to get `coef` and `std_err`), here's the `df`:

```
                           income   balance
statsmodels_coef     2.080898e-05  0.005647
bs_sk_coef          -6.101152e-05  0.002728
statsmodels_std_err  4.985245e-06  0.000227
bs_sk_std_err        2.322953e-06  0.000082
bs_sm_coef           2.072321e-05  0.005655
bs_sm_std_err        1.510824e-07  0.000007
```

-------------EDIT--------------

Here's the definition of `boot_fn`:

```
def boot_fn(data, clf):
    clf.fit(data[["income", "balance"]], data["default"])
    return clf.coef_
```

Furthermore, `coef_` with `sklearn`:

```
X = Default[["balance", "income"]]
y = Default["default"]
clf = LogisticRegression(penalty = "none", solver = "lbfgs")
clf.fit(X, y)
clf.coef_
```

Output:

```
array([[5.64710291e-03, 2.08089921e-05]])
```

To conclude, the 'real' `statsmodels_coef` and `sklearn_coef` are the same, together with the `bootstrap_statsmodels_coef` but the `bootstrap_sklearn_coef` yields a different result.

Why is that?

Comment: Share the definition of `boot_fn` used in the sklearn boostrap?  Do you get similar coefficients with a single (non-boostrapped) fit with sklearn?  Barring errors in `boot_fn`, I suspect feature scaling is the culprit; the solvers sklearn uses tend to perform badly with unscaled inputs.

Comment: Hi, I have added the definition of `boot_fn` and also the coefficients with `non-bootstrapped sklearn`, they are the same as the ones from `statsmodels` and the `bootstrapped statsmodels`. By 'unscaled features' do you mean I should first *standardize* the predictors by dividing them by `np.sqrt(1/n * np.sum(x_ij - x_bar_ij)**2)` ? .. or using the `StandardScalar` function of `sklearn`? (To avoid future problems, should I **always** use `StandardScalar` before fitting the model?)

Comment: To add, I have included a *standardization* of the data in `boot_fn` with `StandardScale().fit_transform(X_train)` but still the coefficients yielded by the `bootstrapped sklearn` are off..

Comment: Hm, very strange that the non-bootstrapped version behaves differently, and that it matches statsmodels suggests it's not an issue of scaling.

Comment: It's not different. The coefficients with `non bootstrapped statsmodels` and `non bootstrapped sklearn` are the same, which are also similar to the `bootstrapped statsmodels`. Only the `bootstrapped sklearn` coefficients are different ..